# How can I pass a LambdaExpression to an IncludeFilter?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-plus

I'm trying to pass a dynamically generated LambdaExpression to an IncludeFilter, as follows:

EDIT: I've changed my test code to the following, as (correctly) I wasn't implementing my "Where" statement. The correct where statement is being generated, but I can't pass the lambda statement into the IncludeFilter call:

```
        DbSet<MyTestEntity> dbSet = db.Set<MyTestEntity>();
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyTestEntity), "t");
        Expression idProperty = Expression.Property(parameter, "mytestentityid");
        Expression delProperty = Expression.Property(parameter, "deleted");
        Expression delTarget = Expression.Constant(false, typeof(bool));
        Expression deletedMethod = Expression.Call(delProperty, "Equals", null, delTarget);
        Expression<Func<MyTestEntity, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyTestEntity, bool>>(deletedMethod, parameter);
        IQueryable<MyTestEntity> query = dbSet.Where(lambda);
        Console.WriteLine("Current Query: {0}", query.ToString());
        foreach (string include in includes)
        {
            Type subType = db.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name.EndsWith(include));
            Assert.IsNotNull(subType);
            ParameterExpression innerParam = Expression.Parameter(subType, subType.Name);
            Assert.IsNotNull(innerParam);
            MemberExpression inrDelProp = Expression.Property(innerParam, "deleted");
            Assert.IsNotNull(inrDelProp);
            ConstantExpression inrDelCstProp = Expression.Constant(false, typeof(bool));
            Assert.IsNotNull(inrDelCstProp);
            MethodCallExpression inrDelMthd = Expression.Call(inrDelProp, "Equals", null, inrDelCstProp);
            Assert.IsNotNull(inrDelMthd);
            var delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(subType, typeof(bool));
            dynamic inrLmbdaExpr = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, inrDelMthd, innerParam);
            Assert.IsNotNull(inrLmbdaExpr);
            Console.WriteLine("inrLmbdaExpr: {0}", inrLmbdaExpr.ToString()); // Result: MyTestEntityChild => MyTestEntityChild.deleted.Equals(false)
            query = query.IncludeFilter(inrLmbdaExpr); // ERROR HERE
            Assert.IsNotNull(query);
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Current Query: {0}", query.ToString());
        }
```

This is built into an abstract class allowing me to pass in an entity type, retrieve the records, and reuse the method irrespective of the entity type; however, I'm also trying to filter out child entities that are marked as deleted (thus the use of EF+).

How can I do this?

EDIT 2: So, I realized I also have Linq.Dynamic.Core (!) in my solution, so I already have access to parsing a LambdaExpression from string. However, the error I get says that IncludeFilter doesn't know which method it's trying to use. (I see in the Object Browser that one uses Expression> and one uses Expression>>. If I could just figure out how to get the IncludeFilter to recognize which method, I think I'd be done! Here's a sample of the code I've rewritten:

`string myIncStr = String.Format("x => x.{0}.Where(s => s.deleted.Equals(false)).Where(x => x.MyEntityId.Equals(IncomingId)",includedEntityName);

IEnumerable<MyEntity> result = db.MyEntity.IncludeFilter(System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(typeof(MyChildEntity), myIncStr, null));`

Is there a way to "force" (for lack of a better term) the IncludeFilter to use one method? Is it by passing a value instead of null in the Parser?

BTW, thanks for your help. Your EFP library is actually excellent.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

Yes, it's possible but only if you can specify the generic argument type required by the method explicitly for the `QueryFilter` (As you mentioned in your comment).

Otherwise, you will need to also call the `QueryFilter` via the expression to make everything generic.

---

However, your current expression seems to have some error such as not calling the `Where` methods.

What you want to achieve is probably something similar to this:

`query = query.IncludeFilter(x => x.Childs.Where(y => !y.Deleted));`

---

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Eval-Expression.NET](http://eval-expression.net/)

This library is not free but makes working with a dynamic expression easier and faster.

Once you get used, you can quickly create a dynamic expression in only a few lines as you normally write LINQ. Here is a code that could handle a similar scenario as your:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Z.Expressions;

namespace Z.EntityFramework.Plus.Lab.EF6
{
    public partial class Form_Request_IncludeFilter_Dynamic : Form
    {
        public Form_Request_IncludeFilter_Dynamic()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // CLEAN
            using (var context = new EntityContext())
            {
                context.MyEntityClasses.RemoveRange(context.MyEntityClasses);
                context.MyEntityClassToFilters.RemoveRange(context.MyEntityClassToFilters);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            // SEED
            using (var context = new EntityContext())
            {
                var entity1 = context.MyEntityClasses.Add(new MyEntityClass {ColumnInt = 1, Childs = new List<MyEntityClassToFilter>()});
                entity1.Childs.Add(new MyEntityClassToFilter {ColumnInt = 1, Deleted = true});
                entity1.Childs.Add(new MyEntityClassToFilter {ColumnInt = 2, Deleted = false});
                context.MyEntityClasses.Add(new MyEntityClass {ColumnInt = 2});
                context.MyEntityClasses.Add(new MyEntityClass {ColumnInt = 3});
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            // TEST
            using (var context = new EntityContext())
            {
                // You must register extension method only once
                // That should not be done here, but for example purpose
                EvalManager.DefaultContext.RegisterExtensionMethod(typeof(QueryIncludeFilterExtensions));

                // That could be also dynamic. I believe you already handle this part
                IQueryable<MyEntityClass> query = context.MyEntityClasses;

                // The path to include
                var include = "Childs";

                // The dynamic expression to execute
                var dynamicExpression = "IncludeFilter(x => x." + include + ".Where(y => !y.Deleted));";
                query = query.Execute<IQueryable<MyEntityClass>>(dynamicExpression);

                // The result
                var list = query.ToList();
            }
        }

        public class EntityContext : DbContext
        {
            public EntityContext() : base("CodeFirstEntities")
            {
            }

            public DbSet<MyEntityClass> MyEntityClasses { get; set; }
            public DbSet<MyEntityClassToFilter> MyEntityClassToFilters { get; set; }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Types().Configure(x =>
                    x.ToTable(GetType().DeclaringType != null
                        ? GetType().DeclaringType.FullName.Replace(".", "_") + "_" + x.ClrType.Name
                        : ""));

                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            }
        }

        public class MyEntityClass
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public int ColumnInt { get; set; }

            public List<MyEntityClassToFilter> Childs { get; set; }
        }

        public class MyEntityClassToFilter
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public int ColumnInt { get; set; }

            public bool Deleted { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Answer question

> Please review my changed code

You are still missing the `where` clause.

What you have is something similar to this as you commented

`// Result: MyTestEntityChild => MyTestEntityChild.deleted.Equals(false)`

What you want is something similar to this

`// Result: MyTestEntityChild => MyTestEntityChild.Where(x => x.deleted.Equals(false))`

**EDIT:** Answer question

Oh sorry, I now understand the problem with it.

If you don't know the type, you will need to call the IncludeFilter in an expression as well to make everything generic. It cannot be called explicitely like you are trying to do.

Comment: Please review my changed code. If there isn't an easier route than a new library for its use, then I'll take that to leadership and check if we can spend the $.

Comment: Let me clarify:
The result statement you reference is the statement I want to inject into the IncludeFilter, so that it looks like this:  `query = query.IncludeFilter(MyTestEntityChild => MyTestEntityChild.deleted.Equals(false));`  
Or are you saying that it needs to look like:  
`query = query.IncludeFilter(MyTestEntityChild => MyTestEntityChild.Where(x => x.deleted.Equals(false)));`  
???   
In either case, the error I get is that the IncludeFilter won't accept a dynamic statement.

Comment: Update: We've decided to go a different way. I saw what you meant about not generating the "Where" statement in my Expression tree, but since my types are unknown at compile time, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to write a statement to do that. I will be looking into this avenue for the future, if it turns out to be a better solution.

Comment: Yup, creating expression is sometimes very hard to develop and maintain. That's why I normally recommend using the Eval-Expressions.NET paid library. It's not free but save a lot of hour of work.

Comment: One other question: I did earlier try to use the IncludeFilter as part of the Expression tree, but ran into the same problem as now (The type arguments for IncludeFilter cannot be inferred from the usage). 
I have the feeling one of these paths is going to be easier to use long-term than the other, so suggestions are welcome.